# How to define an error callback in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-1.6

In my `Controller`:

```
function login(credentials) {
  AuthService
    .login(credentials)
    .then(successCallback, errorCallback);
    //same issue with .then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);
}

function successCallback() {
  // do something after success
}

function errorCallback(data) {
  // do something after error
}
```

and in my `AuthService`:

```
authService.login = function (credentials) {
  return $http
    .post(ENV.apiEndpoint + 'api/v1/login_check', credentials)
    .then(
       function (result) {
        Session.create(result.data.token, result.data.data);
       },
       function (data) {
        Messages.create('Login failed: ' + data.statusText);
       }
    );
}
```

When my `POST` delivers a 200 response code, everything works as expected `do something after success` is executed.

But when my POST results e.g. in a 401 I can see that Messages.create is called (so in this case it enters the `error` path), but unfortunately my Controller calls the `successCallback` and not the `errorCallback`.

I had to migrate this because I was using the deprecated and since Angular 1.6 removed `.success` and `.error` promise attributes. It was working back then, but after migration this doesn't work anymore.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you'll need to throw from the `Messages.create('Login failed: ' + data.statusText);` block

Comment: angulra doesn't like throwing, return `$q.reject()` is better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may **reject** the promise in your error callback.

```
authService.login = function (credentials) {
  return $http
    .post(ENV.apiEndpoint + 'api/v1/login_check', credentials)
    .then(
       function (result) {
         Session.create(result.data.token, result.data.data);
       },
       function (data) {
         Messages.create('Login failed: ' + data.statusText);
         return $q.reject(data);
       }
    );
}
```

---

From [Angular $q doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

> `reject(reason);`
>
> Creates a promise that is resolved as rejected with the specified
>   `reason`. This api should be used to forward rejection in a chain of
>   promises. If you are dealing with the last promise in a promise chain,
>   you don't need to worry about it.
>
> When comparing deferreds/promises to the familiar behavior of
>   try/catch/throw, think of `reject` as the `throw` keyword in JavaScript.
>   This also means that if you "catch" an error via a promise error
>   callback and you want to forward the error to the promise derived from
>   the current promise, you have to "rethrow" the error by returning a
>   rejection constructed via `reject`.